# what is my mistake about making responsive?

Tags: css

I started making my HTML code responsive, but I face white problems,
for example my footer has a background white 4 columns,I think the problem is that I used background for my footer but I don't know how make it responsive.

```css
       h4 {


         font-size: 16px !important;


         font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;


         font-weight: bold;


         color: white;


       }


       .font-icon {


         float: left;


         color: white !important;


         padding: 0 15px 0 0;


         font-size: 25px !important;


       }


       .font-icon:hover {


         color: #80878e !important;


       }


       .footercol p {


         color: white;


       }


       .footercol:nth-child(2) span {


         display: block;


       }


       .footercol {


         float: left;


       }


       .footercol li,


       .footercol span,


       .footercol a {


         color: #80878e;


         font-size: 12px;


         font-family: arial;


         line-height: 2.5;


       }


       .footercol h4 {


         padding: 0 0 20px;


         color: white;


         font-family: 'Open Sans';


         font-size: 16px !important;


         font-weight: bold;


       }


       .footercol li {


         color: white;


         margin: 0 0 0 15px;


       }


       .footercol a {


         text-decoration: none;


       }


       .footercol a:hover {


         color: white;


       }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="footer container-fluid">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="footercol col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-xs-4 col-sm-4">
        <h4>FOLLOW US</h4>
        <div>
          <span class="icon-facebook font-icon"></span>
          <span class="icon-google-plus font-icon"></span>
          <span class="icon-rss font-icon"></span>
          <span class="icon-social-pinterest font-icon"></span>
          <span class="icon-linkedin font-icon"></span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="footercol col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-xs-4 col-sm-4">
        <h4>ADDRESS</h4>
        <span>9870 St Vincent Place,</span>
        <span>Glasgow, DC 45 Fr 45.</span>
        <span>Freephone:  +1 800 559 6580</span>
        <a href="#">mail@demolink.org</a>
      </div>
      <div class="footercol col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-xs-4 col-sm-4">
        <h4>SUPPORT MENU</h4>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Lost Password?</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Forgot your Username?</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Your Membership</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Your Account</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Support Forum</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="footercol col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-xs-4 col-sm-4">
        <h4>ABOUT US</h4>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Customer focus</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Performance</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Affiliates</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">CV Review</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please post your html code in your question.

Comment: and create jsfiddle-example: https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Also, why do you think you need all the `!important`s?

Comment: To address your comment about using bootstrap: you should make a note of that in the question. As it was written originally, neither the question text nor the tags indicated that you were using other libraries. (Of course with the HTML added, classes like `col-lg-3 col-md-4` make that clear, bu those weren't in the text at first.)

Comment: I don't really understand what the problem is, columns seem to work fine.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**: Your first problem is that you're using four divs containing col-sm-4 on a 12 col-based grid. 4*4 = 16. This is making your last div to "jump down" when the screen size is less than 992px wide if I'm not mistaken.

To make things right, you need to understand that Bootstrap is based on a 12 column grid. For example; 
**HTML/markup:**

```
    <div class="container my-footer">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
          <h4>Address:</h4>
          <ul>
            <li>Footer stuff</li>
            <li>Footer stuff</li>
            <li>Footer stuff</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
          <h4>Projects:</h4>
          <ul>
            <li>Footer stuff</li>
            <li>Footer stuff</li>
            <li>Footer stuff</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
          <h4>About us:</h4>
          <ul>
            <li>Footer stuff</li>
            <li>Footer stuff</li>
            <li>Footer stuff</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
          <h4>Contact:</h4>
          <ul>
            <li>Footer stuff</li>
            <li>Footer stuff</li>
            <li>Footer stuff</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```